# apoc.periodic.iterate fails the batch if there is an duplicate data in parameter

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am using an apoc.periodic.iterate query to store millions of data . Since the data may contain duplicates I am using MERGE action to create nodes but unfortunately whenever the data is duplicated the whole batch is getting with error like this

"LockClient[200] can't wait on resource RWLock[NODE(14), hash=1645803399] since => LockClient[200] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(101)"

- Changing parallel as false works fine
- Also by removing duplicates the query is passed successfully

But both of the above solution takes more time since dealing with millions of data . Is there any alternate solution like making a it to wait for the lock

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `parallel:true`, because you are creating relationships in your query. Every time you want to add a relationship to a node, the cypher engine adds a write lock to a node, and other processes can't add to that particular node. That is why you have the write lock exception. Not much you can do except to run it with `parallel:false` setting.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid [deadlocks](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/transaction-management/deadlocks/), concurrent requests that update the DB *should* avoid touching the same nodes or relationships (including the nodes on both ends of those relationships). One way to achieve this is to figure out a way to have the concurrent requests work on disjoint subgraphs.

Or, you can retry queries that throw a `DeadlockDetectedException`. The docs show [an example](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/transaction-management/deadlocks/#transactions-deadlocks-code) of how to do that.